# Controlling whitespace in Pebble templates

Tags: pebble

I'm having a hard time getting the whitespace control the way that I want in a Pebble template. I'm currently generating JSON using Pebble, but this problem and my use case is not specific to JSON (or else I would use a JSON library, such as Jackson instead).

Here's my Pebble template:

```
        "items": {
            {% for item in items -%}
            "{{ item.name }}": "{{ item.value }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        },
```

And, here's the generated output:

```
    "items": {
        "item1": "Value 1",
        "item2": "Value 2"

    },
```

There are two problems with this:

1. I had to have the two blank lines in the template (one before the `endfor` and one after the `endfor`.
2. I still end up with the extra blank line in the output before the closing squiggly bracket, i.e. the `},`.

I'd like for the template to look more like the following:

```
        "items": {
            {% for item in items -%}
            "{{ item.name }}": "{{ item.value }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}     
        },
```

And, I'd like for the resulting output to be:

```
    "items": {
        "item1": "Value 1",
        "item2": "Value 2"
    },
```

I have tried many combinations of the [whilespace control modifier](https://github.com/PebbleTemplates/pebble/wiki/basic-usage#whitespace), but no luck on getting the format that I want.

Comment: Are you able to configure the Pebble `Builder` being used?  If so, calling `newLineTrimming(false)` might help you - that would stop Pebble stripping away newlines that follow a Pebble tag (https://pebbletemplates.io/com/mitchellbosecke/pebble/PebbleEngine/Builder/#method__public_Builder_newLineTrimming_boolean_enableNewLineTrimming)

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace control modifier only trim lines. It doesn't remove line feed. The only solution for your use case is to remove blank lines around {% endfor %}